# Fact tables indicators selectors/filters in an excel report with pivot tables

Tags: excel, excel-services

I'm working in a project where I need to publish some reports based on excel pivot tables against SSAS cube. Until here everything is OK.

However, I want to know how I can set in my excel report a filter or selector with all indicators that are in a fact table of the cube. Any suggestions?

If you know something about this one, let me know please.

Thanks

Regards